# Use session of webbrowser in httprequest

Tags: c#, httprequest, webbrowser-control

I tried to get cookies from a webbrowser control into an httprequest. 
It seems that httprequest works without cookies. 
I used the cookies after logging in. 
I am using cookies from `webbrowser.document.cookies`:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        //request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)";
        if (request.CookieContainer == null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }


        CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();
        string[] array = cookies.Split(new char[]
                    {
                        ';'
                    });
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            string cookie = array[i];
            string name = cookie.Split(new char[]
                        {
                            '='
                        })[0];
            string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
            string path = "/";
            string domain = "upwork.com";
            c.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
        }


        request.CookieContainer = c;

        request.Method = "GET";

        request.KeepAlive = true;


        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```